# Enable KVM on ubuntu 12.04 on virtualbox on iMac'11

Tags: virtualbox, openstack, kvm

I am trying to install Openstack on a Ubuntu 12.04 guest machine running on virtual box and hosted on a iMac'11. More preciesely, I am trying to install the KVM hypervisor on my Ubuntu guest machine.

My Intel i5 processor supports VT-X, however, when I run

```
lili@CloudletVM:~$ sudo kvm-ok
```

I get the following output:

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions 
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

Any one can help me enable KVM on my Virtualbox Guest machine, if possible?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `KVM` in Guest OS running in Virtual Box.

In installation step it's clearly indicated this.

**Determine whether your compute node supports hardware acceleration for virtual machines:**

```
$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

You can use KVM if and only if it returns a non zero value. In your case the above command returns zero. **Even though your original hardware supports hardware acceleration, it's unavailable inside virtual box guest OS**.

So I recommend use `QEMU` instead.

Edit the `[libvirt]` section in the `/etc/nova/nova-compute.conf` file as follows:

```
[libvirt]
...
virt_type = qemu
```